# Where to download a table with ICD-9-CM codes?

Tags: icd-codes

I am looking for a simple table with all ICD9 codes (For example: Diagnosis Code 414.0 -> Coronary atherosclerosis). I can only find weird PDF or other kinds of text documents. Or web forms, where I have to post a certain code to get the description.

### Here is what I have found so far.

http://www.icd9data.com/2015/Volume1/default.html

https://www.aapc.com/codes/icd9-codes-vol3-range

https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Coding/ICD9ProviderDiagnosticCodes/codes

https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/health/practitioner-professional-resources/msp/physicians/diagnostic-code-descriptions-icd-9

https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Publications/

Comment: I wish to access `icd-9cm-2015` as an excel file. Any information or help would be welcome.

Comment: Hi @monapanahifar and welcome to the site. You might think about opening a separate question with a link to this one. Please note I did edit your comment a little. Please check that is what was intended. If not please drop a note in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58858/bioinformatics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zip files found within https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Coding/ICD9ProviderDiagnosticCodes/codes contain text files and Excel spreadsheets that you can open with Excel, R or Python depending on how you want to use this data.

Comment: Thanks, I saw those. However, they seem to have a different format. I will add an example.